# jQuery .animate() 'toggle'

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate

I've been toying with a jQuery navigation menu, and I made a mock up of it for examples sake:
http://jsfiddle.net/DerFlatulator6/3jYhh/1/

I was having an issue where it would do pretty much the exact opposite I wanted it to do. My code for the hover event was like this:

```
$(this)
    .addClass('selected')
    .children('ul')
        .animate({'height': 'toggle'}, 300);
```

After some tinkering, I came up with this

```
$(this)
    .addClass('selected')
    .children('ul')
        .css('height', 'toggle')
        .animate({'height': 'toggle'}, 300);
```

Which works, but I have no idea why! Is anyone able to explain exactly what is happening?

A side question... You'll notice the fiddle has a 3 level menu, where the code is isolated for vertical and horizontal drop downs, would there be good a way to write a function to cover them both, or should I leave it as is?

Comment: So you'd like us to explain to you why your code IS working ?

Comment: I know, it sounds silly, but I'd rather know _why_ it's working so I can better my jQuery knowledge, than just take it for granted any carry on.

Comment: Well, `animate` toggle does just that, toggles the value. When first using `css()` to set the height to nothing, also using toggle, you reverse the animation effect.

Comment: I removed the css toggles and it seemed to make no difference. Also you may want to look into adding .stop() to your animations, otherwise they get queued up.

Comment: AFAIK CSS does not have a 'toggle' value for the height property so have the CSS in the chain makes no sense to me.

Comment: @adeneo But wasn't the `height` already `0`, as it was set to `display: none`, or are they completely exclusive values?

Comment: @j08691 Ok that is weird, I'm even more confused now...

Comment: Actually, was'nt thinking at all, Jay is right, there is no 'toggle' in CSS, it has no effect what so ever. It was just the only difference in the posted code, so I answered a little to fast without thinking about it. Must be somthing else you did wrong =

Comment: Did a little testing, and you could remove most of your code, and it would still do the same, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3jYhh/3/)

Comment: Maybe there was another error somewhere else... @JayBlanchard wouldn't the `'toggle'` be passed to jQuery before CSS though?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, that's great, I didn't realise `toggleClass` would work in that situation, that cuts out the bulk of it!

Comment: The toggle in the .css() method would not be passed.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. I'm unfamiliar with `stop()`, would I just use it like this? `$(this).toggleClass('selected').children('ul').stop().animate({'height': 'toggle'}, 300);`

Comment: Yes, basicly like that, but in this case adding `.stop(true, true)` to both functions would probably be best. Test it by running the mouse fast over the buttons, and make sure there is no queueing of animations.

Answer (score 2):

`animate({'height': 'toggle'}, 300)` is like animate height from current to 0 if height is more the 0 or animate from 0 to previous if current is 0.

from documentation http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings
>   'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding
>   and showing animations that take into account the display type of the
>   element.

Comment: Should it be `'height': 'toggle'`?